# Improve Loading Time with Shopware in Edit-Mode

Tags: time, loading, reload, shopware

I am currently working for the first time with shopware 5, and when the editing mode is activated, my reload time is as high as 50 seconds. my colleagues say "thats how it is in editing mode", but i just cant believe them. are there any tips or tricks to speed up the process? i cant find anything :( even my macbook pro 2017 is freezing up all the time whilst working with this.

Shopware version is 5.2.19

Answer (score 1):

It happens if the compiler cache is deactivated. When you deactivate the compiler cache Shopware always compiles the `less` files on ever request.

Go to the backend, click on **Settings** and open the **Theme Manager**.
Remove the checkbox for the **Disable compiler caching**.

Read more about the theme caching at [Shopware 5 performance guide](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-performance-for-devs/#using-and-configuring-the-theme-cache)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly, i need to be able to do changes in the less files with the results since im doing lots of changes to the less files too. Do you know if it will be faster if i let my php storm compile the less files to css instead of shopware itself

Comment: 1.) you should read the Shopware Designer Guide and specially the part "Best Practice for Theme Development" https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/best-practice-theme-development/